# Uncaught Promises when using UpdateProfile in react firebase

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have went through numerous posts and still unable to solve this issue. I am getting uncaught promises when I try to update the profile for the user.

The following below is my current function. Please help thanks!

```
const createUser = async () => { 
    await addDoc(database.usersRef, { 
            email: emailRef.current.value, 
            fullName: nameRef.current.value, 
            mobileNumber: mobileRef.current.value, 
            status: "Active", 
            userType: userTypeRef.current.value 
        }); 
    };

async function handleSubmit(e) { 
        e.preventDefault() 
        counter++; 
        const password = "Password1!" 
        const secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp({ 
            apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY, 
            authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN 
        }, '' + counter) 
 
        const newAuth = getAuth(secondaryApp); 
 
        try { 
            setError(''); 
            setLoading(true); 
 
            const newUser = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newAuth, emailRef.current.value, password) 
            updateProfile(newAuth.currentUser, { 
                displayName: nameRef.current.value, 
                phoneNumber: mobileRef.current.value 
            }).catch((error) => { 
                console.log(error); 
            }) 
 
            await sendEmailVerification(newUser.user); 
            newAuth.signOut(); 
 
            createUser(); 
 
            setShowModal(true); 
        } catch (e) { 
            console.log(e) 
            setError('Failed to create an account') 
        } 
 
        setLoading(false) 
    }
```

[image: I will get this Error.]

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of this function? `createUser();`. (or show the import statement if it's from a library)

Comment: @NicholasTower Hi Nicholas, thanks for the reply. I have added in the function ```CreateUser()```

Comment: I don't see what's causing the error, but if you'd like to catch the error so you can debug it, then change `createUser()` to `await createUser()`. That will allow the error to go into your `} catch (e) {` block. Without the await, you can only catch synchronous errors, not asynchronous ones.

Comment: Hi @NicholasTower, but there is no issue with ```createUser()``` but it's the updateProfile portion. After commenting on the updateProfile portion everything works fine.

Comment: Ok, the stack trace says it's in createUser, but if updateProfile is the issue, then we'll need to see that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to not mix `async`/`await`/`catch` with `then()`/`catch()`, and instead use one or the other.

Since you're using `try`/`catch`, use `await` on the call to `updateProfile` too, so that any errors will be translated to an exception

```
try { 
    setError(''); 
    setLoading(true); 

    const newUser = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newAuth, emailRef.current.value, password) 
    // 
    await updateProfile(newAuth.currentUser, { 
        displayName: nameRef.current.value, 
        phoneNumber: mobileRef.current.value 
    }) 

    await sendEmailVerification(newUser.user); 
    newAuth.signOut(); 

    createUser(); 

    setShowModal(true); 
} catch (e) { 
    ...
```

Comment: Hi @Frank van Puffelen, it kind of works now? But after testing, it doesn't seem like the phoneNumber is going in. However, displayName does go in.